# Javascript How to generate a dynamic list of time slots

Tags: javascript

I want to generate a list of time slots with an interval of 15 minutes. Now, like Googles calendar for example, I want it to start at 12:00am and after 12:00pm it should display 1:00am until 11:45am.

Here is what I got so far:

```
let x = 15;
let times = [];
let tt = 0;
let ap = ["AM", "PM"];

for (let i = 0; tt < 24 * 60; i++) {
   let hh = Math.floor(tt / 60); 
   let mm = tt % 60; 
   times[i] = ("0" + (hh % 12)).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + mm).slice(-2) + ap[Math.floor(hh / 12)];
   tt = tt + x;
}

console.log(times)
```

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jh5c1ska/) to see it.

Like mentioned before I would like it to start at 12:00am and instead of 00:00pm it should display 12:00pm, then 12:15pm, then 12:30pm etc. etc.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Start is set in your loop (`i = 0`). `0:00pm` is disabled? Than make a simply condition inside loop.

Comment: Don't you mean that instead of 00:00pm it should be 12:00pm?

Comment: @EganWolf oh yes, of course :-) I'll update the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `hh % 12` is equal 0:

```
let x = 15; //minutes interval
let times = []; // time array
let tt = 0; // start time
let ap = ["AM", "PM"]; // AM-PM

//loop to increment the time and push results in array
for (let i = 0; tt < 24 * 60; i++) {
  let hh = Math.floor(tt / 60); // getting hours of day in 0-24 format
  let mm = tt % 60; // getting minutes of the hour in 0-55 format
  let hh12 = hh % 12;
  if( hh12 === 0) {
    hh12 = 12;
  }
  times[i] = ("0" + (hh12)).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + mm).slice(-2) + ap[Math.floor(hh / 12)]; // pushing data in array in [00:00 - 12:00 AM/PM format]
  tt = tt + x;
}

console.log(times);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a start date (at whichever time you wish), then keep adding your interval in minutes until you hit your desired end time (I'm assuming we'll generate slots for the whole day):

```js
let date = new Date(2021, 1, 10, 12, 0, 0);
const intervalMinutes = 15;
const dom = date.getDate();
let times = [];
do {
    times.push(date.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' }))
    date = new Date(date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + intervalMinutes));
} while (date.getDate() === dom)
console.log("Time slots:",times);
```